# Call Azure Service Fabric from outside

Tags: c#, azure, dns, azure-service-fabric

I'm playing with Azure Service Fabric and a console app. I simply want my console app to connect to the cluster and do some stuff.

The console app try to resolve the service address with the following:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        ServicePartitionResolver resolver = null;

        try
        {
            resolver = new ServicePartitionResolver(
                new string[] {
                    "localhost:19000",
                    "localhost:19001"
                });

            Uri serviceUri = new Uri("fabric:/StatefullServiceTEST/MyStatefulService");
            ResolvedServicePartition partition = resolver.ResolveAsync(serviceUri, new ServicePartitionKey(), CancellationToken.None).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Exception: {ex.Message}");
        }
        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.Write("Press any key to exit...");
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
```

My problem is that `resolver.ResolveAsync` throws an exception that doesn't seem to have any connection with Service Fabric:

> Unable to cast COM object of type 'System.__ComObject' to interface
>   type 'IFabricApplicationManagementClient10'. This operation failed
>   because the QueryInterface call on the COM component for the interface
>   with IID '{67001225-D106-41AE-8BD4-5A0A119C5C01}' failed due to the
>   following error: No such interface supported (Exception from HRESULT:
>   0x80004002 (E_NOINTERFACE)).

Any ideas on this?

**UPDATE**

I was not so clear explaining my problem and what I want to achive.

I'm playing with Azure Service Fabric (both stateless and stateful services): my question is: what's the best way to call a micro service hosted in Azure Service Fabric?

Regards,
Attilio

Comment: Very likely due to mismatches in the nuget package versions between what you have (newer) what the cluster has (older). Try to downgrade the Microsoft.ServiceFabric nuget packages to a lower version.

Answer (score 1):

You can't use `ServicePartitionResolver`, it is a reliable service feature and must be called from within a service running in your cluster.

I couldn't understand clearly what you want.

**If you want to manage the service and get details about it, like query running instances or replicas, add or remove instances, and so on, Use the Fabric Client, below is a quick snippet, check details [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/dotnet/api/system.fabric.fabricclient?view=azure-dotnet) and [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/dotnet/api/system.fabric.fabricclient.servicemanagementclient?view=azure-dotnet):**

`

```
using System.Fabric;
using System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates;

string clientCertThumb = "71DE04467C9ED0544D021098BCD44C71E183414E";
string serverCertThumb = "A8136758F4AB8962AF2BF3F27921BE1DF67F4326";
string CommonName = "www.clustername.westus.azure.com";
string connection = "clustername.westus.cloudapp.azure.com:19000";

var xc = GetCredentials(clientCertThumb, serverCertThumb, CommonName);
var fc = new FabricClient(xc, connection);`
```

or,

**If you want to communicate to a running service, like an API, you should use a Reverse Proxy to resolve your services via URL, like the below snippet, more details [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-reverseproxy):**

`http://mycluster.eastus.cloudapp.azure.com:19081/MyApp/MyService`

Comment: I'm trying the FabricClient solution you suggested, but I think there something wrong on my system. The code is the following, very simple:
        try
        {
            FabricClient fabricClient = new FabricClient();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Exception: {ex.Message}");
        }
as suggested in this article but I'm receiving the same exception...
What do you think?
Regards, Attilio

Comment: FabricClient can be used to [*manage*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-deploy-remove-applications-fabricclient) services, not to *call* them afaik.

Comment: Sorry, When you said Connect to the cluster and do some stuff I would imagine you want to manage the application. I added both because didn't know what type of stuff you mean. The first example is to manage and the second is to communicate with the services. I will update my answer to be clear, you could also update your question to make clear what kind of stuff you expect to do.

Answer (score 1):

You have to create a public facing service (such as Asp.net Core Web Api) which will expose the functionality of your service inside service fabric to outside world (outside the service fabric cluster). FabricClient approach is to be utilzied for calling services from within the service fabric cluster and not outside.

From your Asp.net Core service you will use the FabricClient to access the service hosted, so in general your asp.net core app act as reverse proxy to expose the functionality of actual service.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot access service in an ASF cluster from the outside using the `ServicePartitionResolver`.

You have to have a public facing endpoint on your cluster, like a stateless service acting as a web api for example.

From [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-connect-and-communicate-with-services#connections-from-external-clients):

> Services connecting to each other inside a cluster generally can directly access the endpoints of other services because the nodes in a cluster are on the same local network. In some environments, however, a cluster may be behind a load balancer that routes external ingress traffic through a limited set of ports. In these cases, services can still communicate with each other and resolve addresses using the Naming Service, but **extra steps must be taken to allow external clients to connect to services.**
>
> A Service Fabric cluster in Azure is placed behind an Azure Load Balancer. **All external traffic to the cluster must pass through the load balancer**. The load balancer will automatically forward traffic inbound on a given port to a random node that has the same port open. The Azure Load Balancer only knows about ports open on the nodes, it does not know about ports open by individual services.

So, unless your console app is hosted in the cluster as a [guest executable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-deploy-existing-app), you have some more work to do.

Comment: Hi Peter. Thank you for your answer, I'll deepen the argument.