# Could not load file or assembly System.Fabric with Azure Functions

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions, azure-service-fabric, azure-functions-core-tools

Are there any restrictions with packages you can use with Azure Functions.  I have researched as much as I can and it doesn't seem so, however when I try creating an Azure Function that references the package "Microsoft.ServiceFabric" I get the following error:

> System.Private.CoreLib: Exception while executing function:
>   ScaleDownServiceFabrics. FunctionApp2: Could not load file or assembly
>   'System.Fabric, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'. Could not find or load a specific
>   file. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131621). System.Private.CoreLib:
>   Could not load file or assembly 'System.Fabric, Version=6.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'.

I have tried both Azure Func and.1 and 2, and .Net Framework and .Net Core with no luck.

```
using System;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using System.Fabric;

namespace FunctionApp5
{
  public static class Function1
  {
    [FunctionName("Function1")]
    public static void Run([TimerTrigger("*/5 * * * * *")]TimerInfo myTimer, ILogger log)
    {
      log.LogInformation($"C# Timer trigger function executed at: {DateTime.Now}");
      FabricClient client = new FabricClient();
    }
  }
}
```

Is this possible, or a limitation of Azure Functions in Visual Studio - if so, what packages are acceptable?

Comment: ServiceFabric packages are x64 bit, if your function target 32bit it will fail. Can you check that?
Another point is, you have to add the dependencies as packages instead of reference the dll directly in the project, because of the dependencies on other libraries.

Comment: @tank: Diego has provided good checklist for the errors, also can you build the solution with the same and see if you get any errors on error list window, and also make sure to check the solution has all the packages(if using nuget just try to update the packages) and any other referencing dll's , and then test once.

Comment: @diego - I tried changing to x64 (the default with new Azure Function in VS is Any CPU). But got this error: `[13/11/2018 10:08:38 PM] A host error has occurred. 
[13/11/2018 10:08:38 PM] System.Private.CoreLib: Could not load file or assembly 'FunctionApp5, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'.`I don't think this is related.

Comment: @diego - I definitely referenced as a package not DLL.  Package is "Microsoft.ServiceFabric".  I updated the above code to the simplest possible way to replciate the issue.

Comment: @suraj - I am not sure what you mean by "build the solution with the same".  Do you mean in x64?  If so that causes issues above.  All referencing DLLs are in the bin.  Only thing I noticed was that System.Fabric.Dll has File Version 6.0.0.0 but product version 6.3.187.9494 - although I think this counts as 6.0.0.0

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- ServiceFabric packages are x64 bit, if your function target 32bit it will fail. Try the solution proposed by Jerry Liu
- Service Fabric Packages have to be added as packages instead of reference the dll directly in the project, because of the dependencies on other libraries. You should add the NuGet package `Microsoft.ServiceFabric`.
- `Microsoft.ServiceFabric` latest version 6.3.x targets `.Net Standard 2.0` and `.Net Framework` from `4.5` to `4.7.1`, make sure you are using any of these on your project.
- Make sure the `Microsoft.ServiceFabric` DLLs are being copied to the bin folder when built\deployed.
- When you use FabricClient outside the cluster, you have to specify the settings and credentials, otherwise you won't be able to connect to the cluster. See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/48871284/484222) example and [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-connect-to-secure-cluster#connect-to-a-secure-cluster-using-a-client-certificate-1) docs.
- FabricClient uses [Service Fabric API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/servicefabric/sfclient-index) to interact with the cluster, if are having issues with the packages, another option is use HttpClient and make the requests to the API and avoid the packages conflicts

Comment: Hi Diego, many thanks for that - it was the issue!  Is there an easy way to tell if a package is 64 bit only?

Comment: I knew it because I suffered a lot with this Library and is the first check I do. There are many ways, I generally use ILSpy, but you can find many alternatives here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/270531/how-to-determine-if-a-net-assembly-was-built-for-x86-or-x64

Comment: one other question - when I build and deploy this in VSTS - I get this error in Azure Function App: `Function (FeedExports) Error: Unable to load one or more of the requested types. Could not load file or assembly 'System.Fabric, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'. Could not find or load a specific file. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131621).`  I have downloaded the file contents from the Azure Function App and the DLL is there.  Any ideas?

Comment: NEeded to change the Azure function app from 32-bit to 64-bit sorted it.

Comment: I am getting this now in the logs: `Unable to load DLL 'FabricClient.dll' or one of its dependencies: The specified module could not be found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E)`  I guess as the client is not installed on the App Service.  If you got it working - did you just add this DLL to deployment?

Comment: I am not sure what dll is this, the SF DLL I know is  `System.Fabric.dll` within the package and FabricClient is the class inside it. Maybe other dependencies are missing.

Comment: I think the issue is that Service Fabric client is not install on Azure Functions.  Do you think I could just link the required DLLs to the deployment and it would work?  You mentioned you did something similiar so thought you might have come across this.

Comment: Hi, I haven't done for functions, I did with normal services and they were deployed in a service fabric cluster. It is high likely that this  error is because of the SDK is not installed, It has some dependencies on libraries installed by the SDK and `FabricClient.dll` might be one of these, I just checked and it is not part of the package mentioned above. You could try copying these dlls but I would recommend you using the API in functions instead.

Answer (score 4):

Diego and Suraj have pointed out the cause, conflict between 64 and 32 bit.

Two points to fix

1. Set build platform to x64 like what you have done.
2. Get x64 Function runtime. Functions work on Function runtime(contained in Azure Function core tools), but the default bit is x86 downloaded by VS.

To get x64 bit in an easy way, let's use [Nodejs](https://nodejs.org/en/) to install Azure Functions Core Tools from NPM.

After installation, in cmd input `npm i -g azure-functions-core-tools --unsafe-perm true` to get Function core tools.

Then set project debug properties(right click on your project>Properties>Debug blade).

1. Set Launch type to `Executable`
2. Set Executable path to `%appdata%\npm\node_modules\azure-functions-core-tools\bin\func.exe`.
3. Add Application arguments `start`.

Comment: Thanks Jerry - your guide to run in 64-bit sorted it.

Answer (score 1):

I run into exactly same issue as @tank140 commented in original post:

```
Unable to load DLL 'FabricClient.dll' or one of its dependencies: The specified module could not be found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E)
```

More details in [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54873446/service-fabric-client-on-azure-functions-unable-to-load-dll-fabricclient-dll) that I fired on the issue. As answer, it was confirmed that SF Client API for .NET requires that SF runtime is installed on the platform, which is not supported in Azure Functions.

Comment: What I ended up having to do is create an app and run it in the Service Fabric itself unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I just update the azure platform configuration to 64 bit. However, I was using .net core 3.1 function app into win platform.

[image]